# How do i search AD for names like the ones in the "Computers" OU and then move those computers over to their proper location?

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I would like to search Active Directory for a computer with a name like WEB2309 that is currently in "Computers" OU then move it to where other computers have like names.

This what i have currently:

**Takes First member of Computers group**

```
$strFirstMember = get-adgroupmember "Computers"
```

**Cuts off the last number of the first member**

```
$strFirstMember-1 = $strFirstMember.Substring(0,$strFirstMember.Length-1)
```

**Searches for that on AD with a wildcard on the end to find like names**

```
Get-ADObject -Filter { CN -like "$strFirstMember-1*" ObjectClass = "Computer"}
```

Now i need to move firstmember to the location that is found

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Building off what you already have, we get the computer, we strip the last character off of it, and then we get a list of all computers with a similar name. Once we have that list I took a substring of it based off the DistinguishedName property, stripping the name out of it just leaving the OU path. Then I grouped that, sorted the groupings by count to find the OU with the most computers in it with that similar name, and selected the first one. Then I told it to move the computer to that OU.

```
$strFirstMember = get-adgroupmember "Computers"
$strFirstMember-1 = $strFirstMember.Substring(0,$strFirstMember.Length-1)
$Complist = Get-ADComputer -Filter { CN -like "$strFirstMember-1*" }
$NewOU = ($complist|%{$_.DistinguishedName.substring($_.DistinguishedName.indexof(",")+1,$_.DistinguishedName.length-$_.DistinguishedName.indexof(",")-1)}|group|sort count -Descending|select -first 1).name
Move-ADObject $strFirstMember -TargetPath $NewOU
```

Comment: Wont be able to test till tomorrow but this is just what I need.

Answer (score 0):

The following will collect all your computer which match *WEB230** and assign them to variable *$c*

```
$c =  Get-AdComputer -Filter { CN -like "WEB230*"}
```

Moves all found computers to target OU

```
$c | Move-ADObject -TargetPath "ou=YourOu,dc=domain,dc=com"
```

and this will move just the first one, I'm not sure if this is what you mean by *"move firstmember.."*

```
 $c[0] | Move-ADObject -TargetPath "ou=YourOu,dc=domain,dc=com"
```

Comment: The problem is that I don't know which target OU to place them in. I need to grab the location from the Get-AdComputer -Filter { CN -like "WEB230*"}. Then move the original item to the like "WEB230*" location.

Answer (score 0):

I personally prefer Quest Active Directory Cmdlets for AD scripting in Powershell.

This would be the command I use for moves, from a collection of machines already built in a CSV file:

```
Import-Csv "C:\toMove.csv" |`
    ForEach-Object {
    Get-QADComputer $_.Name |`
        Move-QADObject -NewParentContainer "OU=Computers,OU=Locked Computers,DC=com"
    }
```

In one step, you should be able to do something like this too:

```
$comparrisonPC = get-qadComputer "computerToUse"

get-qadComputers -Name "nameStructure*" |`
Where-Object {$_.CN -not $comparrisonPC.ParentContainerDN} |`
Move-QADObject -NewParentContainer "$comparrissonPC.ParentContainerDN"
```

I don't have a test domain to test it on, but it should work...